# NameError: name 'index' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I have started my first django project and having an issue with adding a view to my urlpatters.

**project/first_app/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('test')
```

**project/project/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from first_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name=index),
]
```

This is throwing the below error in my server terminal

```
  File "/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/project/project/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
path('first_app', views.index, name=index),
NameError: name 'index' is not defined
```

I've played around with the path: `path('first_app'` quite a lot and can't seem to get it working.

Comment: You forgot to put "index" in quotes - you meant it as a string, not the name of a variable. Check out the [django manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/) on the url dispatcher.

Comment: that was it - thanks. I also had to remove first_app from my path string

Answer (score 2):

It is not about which url you are calling. Somewhere your code has --Index-- which isn't defined properly, which obviously a python variable without definition. Give the **--index--** as a string to name parameter in your path like this.

change your url **from**:

```
path('', views.index, name=index),
```

**to:**

```
 path('', views.index, name='index'),
```

for more info:
see this example [django path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#django.urls.path)